# Updating SQL checkbox without array

Tags: php, sql, checkbox, sql-update

I have this code where I can add and later on update multiple checkbox. I can already add the value of the of checkbox into the database but I'm having problem when updating it. The value inserted into the database for checkbox is either 1 or 0.

Insert HTML code :

```
<tr>
  <td align="center" width="150"><input type="hidden" name="leave_al" value="0" />
                                 <input type="checkbox" name="leave_al" value="1">Annual Leave </td>
  <td align="center" width="150"><input type='text' size='15' name='annual_days' id='annual_days'> day(s) </td>
</tr> 

<tr>
  <td align="center" width="150"><input type="hidden" name="leave_matl" value="0" />
                                 <input type="checkbox" name="leave_matl" value="1">Maternity Leave </td>
  <td align="center" width="150"><input type='text' size='15' name='maternity_days' id='maternity_days'> day(s) </td>
</tr>
```

Update HTML code :

```
<?php 
        if ($row2['leave_al'] == 1)
        {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='leave_al' value='1' checked> Annual Leave </td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='leave_al' value='0'> Annual Leave </td>";
        }

        if ($row2['leave_matl'] == 1)
        {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='leave_matl' value='1' checked> Maternity Leave </td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='leave_matl' value='0'> Maternity Leave </td>";
        }
    ?>
```

Update process code :

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $leave_al = $_POST['leave_al'];
    $leave_matl = $_POST['leave_matl']; 

    $query = "UPDATE leaves 
    SET leave_al = '".$leave_al."', leave_matl = '".$leave_matl."',
    WHERE emp_id= '$id'";
}
```

Based on the coding above, when I checked the box, the value 1 or 0 is not been saved in the database.

A lot of examples I've seen showed on how to update with array. If you could help me guide the correct way to update the checkbox and changed the 1 0 value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Initially the problem I see is you never set $id on your UPDATE statement. Perhaps you need:

```
$id = $_POST['leave_id'];
```

(I'm not sure how you set the id in your form).

Secondly, remove the hidden inputs - they aren't necessary and if you move code around could cause problems.

On the processing code, change this line:

```
$leave_al = $_POST['leave_al'];
```

to

```
$leave_al = ($_POST['leave_al']=="1"?1:0);
```

That's the terniary operator - it says "if it is == 1 then set $leave_al to 1 otherwise $leave_al is 0. That way your update stmt is correct whether the checkbox was checked or not.